# Why is recursive MergeSort faster than iterative MergeSort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I just implemented the two algorithms and I was surprised when I plotted the results! Recursive implementation is clearly faster than the iterative one.
After that, I added the insertion sort combined with both of them and the result was the same.

In the lectures we use to see that recursive is slower that iterative like in factorial calculation but here it doesn't seem to be the case. I pretty sure that my codes are right. **What's the explenation for this behaviour?** It look like java (10) implements automatically a multithread in recursion mode cause when I display the little animation the insertion sort works in parallel with merge operations.

If these codes are not enough to understand here is my github: [Github](https://github.com/Molesox/Algorithme/tree/master/src/Sorting/src)

**EDIT RELOADED**
As said in comments I should compare things that are similar so now the merge method is the same in iterative and recursive.

```
private void merge(ArrayToSort<T> array, T[] sub_array,
                   int min, int mid, int max) {
    //we make a copy of the array.
    if (max + 1 - min >= 0) System.arraycopy(array.array, min, sub_array, min, max + 1 - min);

    int i = min, j = mid + 1;

    for (var k = min; k <= max; k++) {

        if (i > mid) {
            array.array[k] = sub_array[j++];
        } else if (j > max) {
            array.array[k] = sub_array[i++];
        } else if (sub_array[j].compareTo(sub_array[i]) < 0) {
            array.array[k] = sub_array[j++];
        } else {
            array.array[k] = sub_array[i++];
        }
    }
}
```

Sort Recursive:

```
public void Sort(ArrayToSort<T> array) {
    T sub[] = (T[]) new Comparable[array.Length];
    sort(array, sub, 0, array.Length - 1);
}

private InsertionSort<T> insertionSort = new InsertionSort<>();
private void sort(ArrayToSort<T> array, T[] sub_array, int min, int max) {
    if (max <= min) return;
    if (max <= min + 8 - 1) {
        insertionSort.Sort(array, min, max);
        return;
    }
    var mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
    sort(array, sub_array, min, mid);
    sort(array, sub_array, mid + 1, max);
    merge(array, sub_array, min, mid, max);

}
```

Sort Iterative:

```
private InsertionSort<T> insertionSort = new InsertionSort<>();
public void Sort(ArrayToSort<T> array) {

    int length = array.Length;
    int maxIndex = length - 1;

    T temp[] = (T[]) new Comparable[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i += 8) {
        insertionSort.Sort(array, i, Integer.min(i + 8 - 1, maxIndex));
    }

    System.arraycopy(array.array, 0, temp, 0, length);

    for (int m = 8; m <= maxIndex; m = 2 * m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i += 2 * m) {

            merge(array, temp, i, i + m - 1,
                    Integer.min(i + 2 * m - 1, maxIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

In the new plot we can see that now the difference is proportional (*à un facteur près*). If someone has any more ideas... Thanks a lot :)
The new * new plot
[image: iterative vs recursive plot]

And here is my (teacher's one in fact) method to plot:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbSteps; i++) {
    int N = startingCount + countIncrement * i;
    for (ISortingAlgorithm<Integer> algo : algorithms) {

        long time = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < folds; j++) {
            ArrayToSort<Integer> toSort = new ArrayToSort<>(
                    ArrayToSort.CreateRandomIntegerArray(N, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (int) System.nanoTime())
            );
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            algo.Sort(toSort);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            time += (endTime - startTime);
            assert toSort.isSorted();
        }
        stringBuilder.append(N + ", " + (time / folds) + ", " + algo.Name() + "\n");
        System.out.println(N + ", " + (time / folds) + ", " + algo.Name());
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you do insertion sort in your iterative?

Comment: That's a good question, I thought that it was better to do insertion for small tabs. Anyway, the plot was made without insertion sort in both algorithms.

Comment: But as I said with or without insertion sort, plots are similar.

Comment: Furthermore, an individual test shows that insertion sort in the iterative method improves a little bit the speed (but it might be a coincidence)

Comment: In your recursive version, you use `System.arraycopy` to copy subarrays, but in your iterative version, you use a loop to do that. Considering that `System.arraycopy` is highly optimized, it's going to be faster than your loop. Also, in the iterative version you use insertion sort to sort 8-element subarrays, but then you start your merge on 4-item subarrays. Seems like you should start with 8-item subarrays.

Comment: Yeah, indeed m=4 is a huge mistake! So I changed that and I have transformed my "for"s and "while"s in System.arraycopy(...) to optimise and indeed there is a big improvement but it remains slower than recursivity :(

Comment: Your `merge` methods are significantly different, when they should be identical. Not only are the loop constructs different, in the recursive version you pass `temp` as a parameter, and in the iterative version `temp` is a global. Examine your code closely, and make sure that support functions (like the insertion sort and the merge) are *identical*. If you want to see the difference between recursion and iteration, you have to make sure to isolate them. Otherwise, can't determine where the differences are.

Comment: @JimMischel you are right! I have done what u say so use the same merge method and everything is similar now (attributes...) but sadly is still slower. At least now the difference is proportional.

Comment: The iterative sort method you show doesn't pass a temp array to the `merge` method. The iterative sort method makes a complete copy of the array in temp. Apparently for no reason. The recursive method doesn't do that. Or perhaps something prior to calling the recursive version does. Please post an update that shows the exact code you've used. Include the iterative and recursive `sort` methods, and the `merge` method. Also, post your test/timing code, because the difference could be there.

Comment: ok I founded! Merge methods must be different!

Comment: Kindly provide your code in GitHub, as link doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I have an answer because I didn't try your code.
I will give you thoughts:

a) CPU have L1 cache and instruction prefetching. The recursive version may have better locality of references when all the sorts are done and it is finishing with a bunch of merges while poping all frames (of for other cpu optimzation reasons)

b) Meanwhile the JIT compiler does crazy things to recursion, particularly due to tail recursion and inlining. I suggest you try without JIT compiler just for fun. Also might want to try changing the thresholds for JIT compilation, so it gets JIT compiled faster for minimizing the warmup time.

c) system.arraycopy is a native method and despite being optimized, it should have overhead.

d) the iterative version seems to have more arithmetics in the loops.

e) that is an attempt at micro-benchmarking. you need to factor out the GC and have tests running dozens if not hundreds of times. Read up on JMH. Also try different GCs and -Xmx.